# Android - view disappear during animation

Tags: android, animation

I got custom animation, create on runtime just to simple translate.
Everything is working fine, got no problems with it, but on
Nexus 10 with latest android animation randomly start disappear and
than I can't do anything but restart the app.
Everything is working, I can see the view on the first and last frame of the animation, the issue is just during the animation, like it won't render it.

When I highlight all the nested layouts I can see that animation occur.

The app is complex, cause I got Unity player as subview and also video view in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was "GONE" parameter on one of the views which was causing that issue. I replace it with "INVISIBLE" and this fix it.